# How can sslcert and sslkey be passed as environment variables in Kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm trying to make my app connect to my PostgreSQL instance through an encrypted and secure connection.

I've configured my server certificate and generated the client cert and key files.

The following command connects without problems:

```sh
psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem \
  sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem \
  hostaddr=<instance_ip> \
  port=5432 \
  user=db dbname=dbname"
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to pass the client key as value, I can only pass the file path. Even using the default environment variables from psql, this is not possible: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html

Golang follows the same specifications as lib-pq and there is no way to pass the cert and key values: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq?tab=doc#hdr-Connection_String_Parameters.

I want to store the client cert and key in environment variables for security reasons, I don't want to store sensitive files in github/gitlab.

Comment: Just put your cert and key files outside of your project's directory tree.  Put them in the running user's home directory or in /usr/local/etc depending on how you plan to do deployments.

Comment: This app will be deploy on Kubernetes using docker images. How can I do this while doing CI/CD?

Comment: Mount the client certificate and key as a volume and point to them. Otherwise, you might be able to get to the underlying `tls.Config` object for lib/pq, but you'll have to research that.

Comment: @Vivi you want to use secrets https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: If I mount the files, can I modify my deployment without lose them? For example, deploy a new app version

Comment: @StevenEckhoff I though secrets were read as environment variables, can I declare them as file?

Comment: @StevenEckhoff I just foud out there, Thank you! It's exactly what I need!

Comment: yes you can also create secrets from files. Then you can have them mounted by k8s at a specified location. You can set another environment var to specify the path.

Comment: @Vivi Secrets are persistent objects, so when you edit your deployment the secret will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the values in your environment and you can get them in a init function.

```
func init() {
   var := os.Getenv("SOME_KEY")
}
```

When you want to set these with K8s you would just do this in a yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
data:
  SOME_KEY: the-value-of-the-key
```

Then to inject into the environment do.

```
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
    name: my-secret
```

Now when your init function runs it will we able to see SOME_KEY.

If you want to pass a secret as a file you do something like this.

```
kubectl create secret generic my-secret-files --from-file=my-secret-file-1.stuff --from-file=my-secret-file-2.stuff
```

Then in your deployment.

```
volumes:
  - name: my-secret-files
    secret:
      secretName: my-secret-files
```

Also in your deployment under you container.

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: my-secret-files
    mountPath: /config/
```

Now your init would be able to see.

```
/config/my-secret-file-1.stuff
/config/my-secret-file-2.stuff
```

Comment: While this answer helps with passing environment variables as secrets, it doesn't answer the question: how does one pass the client certificate and key as environment variables and use them in lib/pq. This cannot be done just by passing a variable (access to the underlying tls.config object isn't so trivial).